# Get logs "Cannot use import statement outside a module " when run code in TypeScript Playground

Tags: typescript, typescript-playground

I had added Custom npm Modules `lodash` in the TypeScript Playground plugins tab.

[image]

The TS config looks fine as well. When I run below code:

```
import _, { Dictionary } from 'lodash';

export function omitFalsyFields<T extends Dictionary<any>>(params: T) {
  return _.omitBy(params, (k) => !k);
}

interface CreateUserParams {
  name?: string;
  email: string;
}

const params = omitFalsyFields({ name: '', email: 'example@gmail.com' })
console.log(params)
```

Got logs:

[image]

```sh
[ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
[ERR]: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

When I check the console of my browser, It seems these two errors are thrown by `react_devtools_backend.js`. My code doesn't include any React code.

[image]

What's going on? I expect the `console.log(params)` to execute correctly and print the log.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfQDRwN5wCLAMY2BAOwEMoBPOAXzgDMoIQ4ByAGwgBMiBnAC0YG4AUAICmAD0iwaAVwK58BOPWAwAYkWadSK4MOZtOAHgAqcMTGEF9mHHkIlSBogVIA+FwAowJIiE4AuOCMASjQBODgoYRgpKAUEADolGAAhUk9vXxR3AGsQgF4XOABCXMEKIWACcyhqImxhOABhSKJzAFVOYSgABQzOUPDiEGEAfgDOGChKgHNBcOEQImBmccmZsqFsQgm4LygffrzFEGU1DS0dPU53dCHhAMZGFAWllaYxHzBmYQABacXlvEtiBGJQggItgROBBvvFWNN0vtfOCBEA)

Comment: I don't think you can import some modules (or maybe not even any of them) in the playground. For that you might want to use a real sandbox like sandbox.io

Answer (score 2):

I got imports to work in ts playground with this hacky solution below:

```
const AsyncFunction = (async () => {}).constructor as FunctionConstructor;
const _import = (mod: string) => {
    return (new AsyncFunction('', `return import('https://cdn.skypack.dev/${mod}')`))()
}

import type { Dictionary } from 'lodash';

(async () => {

const _ = await _import('lodash') as typeof import('lodash');

function omitFalsyFields<T extends Dictionary<any>>(params: T) {
  return _.omitBy(params, (k) => !k);
}

interface CreateUserParams {
  name?: string;
  email: string;
}

const params = omitFalsyFields({ name: '', email: 'example@gmail.com' })
console.log(params)

})()
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wggZBw)

You do need to change your module setting to commonjs for this to work, maybe a better solution is to write a [playground plugin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dev/playground-plugins/) to transform normal imports to this format or something similar.

Comment: That is insane!